# Where is torch.matmul implemented?

Tags: python, pytorch

Where is `torch.matmul` implemented, especially the part that runs on the GPU?

The whole project is 2M lines of code. I tried to `grep` the sources of the `1.8.2` release, but have trouble finding this function. I'm guessing it's generated from something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be implemented below:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/LinearAlgebra.cpp#L1450

The `matmul` function included by the [Functions.h](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/file_build_aten_src_ATen_Functions.h.html#file-build-aten-src-aten-functions-h) and [ATen.h](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/file_aten_src_ATen_ATen.h.html) included `Functions.h`
And inside pytorch api([pytorch/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/linalg.h](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/linalg.h)), it includes `<ATen/ATen.h>`

So:

pytorch/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/linalg.h > ATen > Functions > LinearAlgebra > matmul

Comment: Just adding a tip. Clone the repository and open it with vscode, then in the left bar you can search for code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is in [this file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/f9c0a39ad9320795fc8df77b570c317e0c2ab60e/aten/src/ATen/native/mkldnn/Matmul.cpp).

Comment: This looks like an MKL binding (no GPU).